# Bash extract double quotes command to param

Tags: bash

Very entry level question.

For the given working script:

```
#!/bin/bash
./configure $FLAGS --extra-cflags="-I$TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX/include $CFLAGS"
```

Is it possible to extract the `"-I$TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX/include $CFLAGS"` part into a parameter?

E.g. Amongst others, I tried the following which will fail with *unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'* :

```
#!/bin/bash
EXTRACT="\"-I$TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX/include $CFLAGS\""
./configure $FLAGS --extra-cflags=$EXTRACT
```

Comment: Don't confuse syntactic quotes -- which tell the shell how to parse strings into syntactic elements -- with literal quotes, which are part of your data. They're *completely* different things, and literal quotes do not in any way serve a syntactic purpose (putting extra quotes in your data can't substitute for missing quotes in your syntax).

Comment: (Also, `./configure $FLAGS` is only "working" for a loose definition thereof -- the set of possible arguments you can pass in FLAGS is quite severely restricted. There's no possible way to give `FLAGS='--foo="bar baz"'` the same effect as `./configure --foo="bar baz"`, for example).

Comment: (And as another aside -- all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to OS- or shell-defined tools, whereas variables with at least one lowercase character in their names are reserved for application use. Thus, while `CFLAGS` is well-defined as living in reserved space, if `TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX` is your own construction, it should have at least one lowercase character; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EXTRACT="-I$TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX/include $CFLAGS"
./configure $FLAGS --extra-cflags="$EXTRACT"
```

[Word Splitting on Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)